# opening Blender, empty white screen

Tags: interface

I installed Blender and once I run it this is all I get[image]

I have a win 7 64 bits and I already have the latest drivers of my graphic card

Comment: what GPU are you using?

Comment: I have a nvidia geforce 9800 gtx/gtx+   also I made this thing I found in the link                                                                                               "Download opengl32.dll from ftp://ftp.blender.org/sergey/softwaregl/ and put it next to blender.exe. This will switch blender to fully software opengl"                                                                                                          and now it seems i can open the program but it go slow... this means is a NVIDIA driver problem which means I need to wait for the next driver update to be fixed?

Comment: @arklight or you can rollback to a previous version of the driver. most graphic cards install a little utility program that enable/disable different settings , see if disabling a feature can fix blender.

Comment: I installed old versions of the drivers and old versions of Blender and there is something strange it always happens: it works - restart PC - dont works - uninstall drivers - it works but in low quality - instal new driver - it works - restart PC - dont works - (repeat)

Comment: what I'm triying to say is it seems once I restart my pc I need to install again the drivers and it will be fine until I restart my pc, is like every time I need to restart my PC I need to do all of this again and again, also when the program works windows movie maker too, if not both dont work, sounds like a problem with graphic card or at least it seems

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who either have this problem, like I do, or will have the problem in the future, arklight posted a .dll to download. Once I moved that into the folder with my blender.exe it instantly fixed it.

> I have a nvidia geforce 9800 gtx/gtx+ also I made this thing I found in the link "Download opengl32.dll from ftp.blender.org/sergey/softwaregl and put it next to blender.exe. This will switch blender to fully software opengl" and now it seems i can open the program but it go slow... this means is a NVIDIA driver problem which means I need to wait for the next driver update to be fixed? – arklight Jun 12 '16 at 15:20

Answer (score -3):

Right Click -> Run with Graphics Processor -> Integrated Graphics

Enjoy :)

Comment: right click on what?